# Efficient ways for Python debugging when called from within C++ code

Tags: python, debugging

I have a C++ application (on Windows XP) that invokes some Python code. I currently use Winpdb as my python debugger.

Using winpdb as the debugger has some disadvantages since firstly, I need to add a pdb statement, and there is little control afforded to me during the execution since I add dynamic breakpoints.

Does anyone know of tools that can be used that work in a similar fashion to Visual Studio 2010 (or Visual Studio in general)? Most important for me is to be able to set up and remove breakpoints while the application is executing, much like we can do using Visual Studio.

I have looked at ActiveState Komodo IDE6 and Eclipse Python PyDev, but I do not think either one actually fits the bill. This is because I have various python modules that are initialized
using the C++ function call "Py_InitModule" with a name that might be different from the name of the .py file. There modules are not recognized by Komodo and Eclipse Python PyDev.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for me it seems that it'd work in PyDev... The only thing is that you have to attach the tracing to the debugger -- use pydevd.settrace(suspend=False) on the thread you want to trace and after that it should 'synchronize' the current breakpoints and their additions/removals ( more references: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html ) -- note that you could use pydevd.settrace(suspend=True) to work as a breakpoint as in in pdb.

I didn't really understand why you said it wouldn't work. Can you post your specific example of what's not working to see how that would be solvable? (some things may be customized in pydevd_file_utils.py to help in translating breakpoint paths).

Comment: Dear Fabio, Thank you for your response. After your suggestions, I was able to debug the C++ application using Pydev and Eclipse. I had not read the details regarding remote debugging since I thought it was to do exclusively with debugging an application running on a remote machine. Thanks again.